# Need a jQuery styler (aka form skinner) to beautify all input types

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I need an all in one jQuery input type styler which beautifies selectbox, radiobuttons, checkboxes, textbox, textareas, multiselect, file inputs etc. I'm searching vigorously, but all I got doesn't fit the case.

Some of them are handy but validation engines doesn't work for them, some of them doesn't support beautification on ajax page, some of them doesn't allow to beautify their dropdown lists, some of the plugins only provides to beautify the selectbox. Please suggest me a plugin.

P.S: I have already tried jQtransform (which is now deprecated), Uniform etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try **[uniformjs](http://uniformjs.com/)**

```
<!-- Make sure your CSS file is listed before jQuery -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="uniform.default.css" media="screen" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.uniform.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
 // On load, style typical form elements
 $(function () {
     $("select, input, button").uniform();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Milind, Uniformjs is a great plugin. But the styled selextboxes  doesn't allow the styling of the dropdown tray. :(

Comment: You might wanna add your own css for that part.

Comment: Most of the styling plugins adds <ul><li> tags to style the tray and then add style to them which sometime makes it almost impossible to validate in simple "class" based validation, it seems to be the styling of default html select box tray is not possible. May be I'm wrong.